# caffe check failed: kernel_size specified 2 times; 0 spatial dims

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I have a caffe "Check failed" error as:

```
...
I0415 15:35:30.497133 39410 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 1 4096 (4096)
I0415 15:35:30.497135 39410 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 2898304
I0415 15:35:30.497138 39410 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer conv1
I0415 15:35:30.497155 39410 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer conv1
I0415 15:35:30.497169 39410 net.cpp:406] conv1 <- ReLU0
I0415 15:35:30.497174 39410 net.cpp:380] conv1 -> conv1
F0415 15:35:30.497185 39410 base_conv_layer.cpp:35] Check failed: num_kernel_dims == 1 || num_kernel_dims == num_spatial_axes_ kernel_size must be specified once, or once per spatial dimension (kernel_size specified 2 times; 0 spatial dims).
```

and here is a little part of the proto.txt file:

```
...
layer {
  name: "loss0"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "ampl0"
  bottom: "label_b4_noise"
  top: "loss0"
}
layer {
  name: "ReLU0"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "ampl0"
  top: "ReLU0"
  relu_param {
    negative_slope: 0
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "ReLU0"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    bias_term: false
    pad: 0
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 1
    stride: 1
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
    axis: 1
  }
}
...
```

could you please tell me why "Check failed"?

what "kernel_size specified 2 times; 0 spatial dims" means?

what num_spatial_axes_ kernel_size is here?
sorry if my question is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the input for your layer (`"ReLU0"`):

> ```
> I0415 15:35:30.497133 39410 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 1 4096 (4096)
> ```

Its dimensions are 1x4096 that is, it has 1 batch with 4096 channels with **no** width and **no** height (that is, width and height are singleton dimensions that are usually ignored).
Now you want to apply `"conv1"` a 1x5 kernel. How do you want to apply a convolution on a blob that has no spatial dimensions?!

This is the error you got from caffe: you specified 2 spatial dimensions for conv kernel (you specified `kernel_size` twice) but your input blob has no spatial dimensions at all, that is its `num_spatial_axes_==0`.

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong:
so, this "no width and no height" is caused by loss 0? (i have a loss0 in the middle of network!)

Comment: @NimaHatami I suspect your signal becomes 1D before it is fed to the loss layer. Check the log to see blobs shapes, you should see where your signal becomes 1D. Usually this happens if you have an `"InnerProduct"` layer.

Comment: yes, you are so right, before loss0 there is a "InnerProduct" layer!
how should i change it to be adapted to the next layer?

Comment: layer {
  name: "ampl0"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "unet1"
  top: "ampl0"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    bias_term: false
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}

Comment: so, can you tell me how to add width and height? 1 4096 => 1 1 1 4096?
how to use reshape here?

Comment: you can use `axis: 0` parameter to `conv1`, thus defining the second dimension to be a "spatial" dimension. Then you only need `kernel_size: 5` (once) since you have a 1D signal with 1D kernel. @NimaHatami